# A .py file which compiled from .qrc file( using pyside-rcc ) does not work

Tags: python, image, pyside, qt-designer, rcc

I am working on python project and I have a problem with my .py file which complied from .qrc file. First, let I explain briefly about my project.

I created my project GUI in QtDesigner and also use the image in the GUI. Then, I generate .py from .ui file using pyside-uic and generate .py file from .qrc file using pyside-rcc. The problem is when I use the .py file (an image file), images does not show in my GUI.

Is anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you for all your answer. :)

Ps. I use PySide as my GUI language.

Comment: Can u supply simple summary about your code and qrc file ?

Answer (score 7):

Have you actually added the resource to your GUI project?

Starting from scratch, here's how to do it:

In Qt Designer, select View > Resource Browser. Then, in the Resource Browser, click the Edit Resources button. From there, you can either create a new resouce file, or open an existing one. The important thing is that the resource file must be able to access the resources (e.g. image files) using *relative* paths. So that means they must be either in the same directory as the resource file, or one of its sub-directories.

Once you've created the resource file, add a prefix (e.g. "images") using the buttons below the right-hand pane, then add your images (or whatever), and finally click Ok.

Now when you want to add a pixmap to a label, just make sure you select the image from your new resource, rather than the file on disk.

The final steps are to re-generate your GUI module using `pyside-uic` and generate the resources module using `pyside-rcc`. When you do this, make sure the resources module is saved as "resource_rc.py" in the *same directory* as the GUI module:

```
    pyside-uic -o widget.py widget.ui
    pyside-rcc -o resource_rc.py resource.qrc
```

(PS: if your are using packages in your project, you should use the `--from-imports` option with `pyside-uic` to get relative imports).

Comment: I followed these steps exactly but pyside-rcc results in 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/jmason86/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pyside-rcc
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6 

Everything is in a single directory together. I've also tried moving the image into a subdirectory called images with everything else the same. No dice.

Comment: @JamesPMason. Your problem has got nothing to do with the instructions which I gave. There is obviously something wrong with your pyside installation (but I don't know exactly what).

Comment: You're right! These instructions worked perfectly once I did this really weird fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480902/pyside-rcc-dyld-library-not-loaded/28502438