# An images does not show in the program, using PySide and QtDesigner

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, qt-designer

I am working on my Python project and use PySide as my GUI language. I had ask the same question about 1 week ago but the answer cannot solve my problem.
So, I ask the new question and provide more details about my project.

My previous question is here: [A .py file which compiled from .qrc file( using pyside-rcc ) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508491/a-py-file-which-compiled-from-qrc-file-using-pyside-rcc-does-not-work)

I generate .py file from .ui file using pyside-uic, and generate .py file from .qrc file using pyside-rcc.

This is my file path and inside .qrc file

[image]

*The CLoginWidget.py is generated by pyside-uic and CLoginWidgetRes_rc.py is generated by pyside-rcc

[image]

And here is my example code using these resources

```
self.enterButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    image: url(:/button/res/login_enter_button.gif);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    image: url(:/button/res/login_entered_button.gif);\n"
"}")
```

The problem is the images does not show in my program.
Is anyone know what happens and how to solve this problem.

Thank you for all answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem in your example seems to be with the stylesheet-syntax. The [QSS properties reference](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) for `image` states that:

> This property is for **subcontrols** only - we don't support it for other
>   elements.

So it obviously won't work with a `QPushButton`, since it doesn't have any subcontrols. Perhaps you meant to use `border-image` or `background-image`?

These properties work exactly as expected for me, if I set up the resource module using the approach outlined in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22517901/984421) on this subject.

Here is the actual stylesheet I tested with:

```
    self.button.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
            background-image: url(:/button/res/image.gif);
        }
        """)
```

**EDIT**:

Below is a minimal working example that shows how to use a resource correctly in pyside. All you need to do is ensure that there is an image file called `res/login_enter_button.gif`, and then save the example files below in the directory containing the `res` directory. You can then do:

```
pyside-uic -o example_ui.py example.ui
pyside-rcc -o example_rc.py example.qrc
```

and everything will work as expected.

**example.qrc**:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="button">
    <file>res/login_enter_button.gif</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**example.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Window</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Window">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>171</width>
    <height>61</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Hello World</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Test</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="example.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**example.py**

```python
from PySide import QtGui
from example_ui import Ui_Window

class Window(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Window):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-image: url(:/button/res/login_enter_button.gif);
            }
            """)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work.
In the QtDesigner, I use 'image' instead of 'background-image' and it works. But when I use 'image' with my code, it does not work (also 'background-image').

Comment: @PandarianLd. I have updated my answer to include a **known working** example. If you are doing things properly, it should be easy for you test it and confirm that it also works for you. You can then compare with your real application to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Your solutions is work!! I try to understand the way of defining an image path. Now, I have to look and check what's wrong in my code. Thank you very much @ekhumoro . I am very appreciate you for all of your suggestion and follow up my problem. I hope that my project will be OK soon and I will let you know when it works. Thank you again ;)

Comment: Can it be a case that different computer will give the different result? I am working with my partner. Both of us using Toshiba Notebook (different model) and Python 3.3.2 32 bit. When run the project in my notebook, it works. On the other hand, running in my partner notebook, it does not work. I do not know what happens here.

Comment: @PandarianLd. Glad to see you are making some progress. The only reason I can think of why my example doesn't work on the other machine, is that the qt library was compiled without gif support. Try using some other image formats (jpg, png) to see if that makes any difference. Are both machines running the same OS?

Comment: Both machines are running the same OS, Windows 7. **I use 'pyside-rcc -py3' instead of only 'pyside-rcc'. My partner also use this function.