# pyside-rcc "dyld: Library not loaded:..."

Tags: macos, pyqt4, pyside, enthought, canopy

I'm a python and Qt rookie and I have some problems running pyside-rcc (and pyrcc4). The problem is not the link to the executable but a library problem it seems. That I'm not a unix wizard, probably doesn't help either:)

When I run `$ pyside-rcc` i get the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pyside-rcc
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

For `$ pyrcc4` the error is similar but not exactly the same:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml
  Referenced from: /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pyrcc4
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

- I'm running Mac OS X 10.9
- I have Enthought Canopy (v.1.5.1) installed with the following
  packages: Qt 4.8.5-10, PySide 1.2.2, PyQt 4.11.0-1
- I have also installed Qt Creator (3.3.0) which came with Qt 5.4.0

To activate the Canopy python packages system wide I have the following line in mt `.bash_profile`

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

I have found a lot of posts with `dyld: Library not loaded...` errors but I can't find the right path to the Qt framework and thus, I'm stuck... Does anyone with Enthought Canopy have the same problem?

Thank you in advance, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I found a similar question here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9024

The libraries (when installed through Canopy) is in `/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib`

Apparently they should be in `/Library/Frameworks` After copying them here it works...

Comment: My god.. thank you! Several hours trying to figure this out. How'd you figure out that's where they were supposed to be?

Comment: Honestly it been so long that I can't remember the details, but it is mentioned [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/8814/solved-pyside-new-mac-os-install-can-t-load-qtcore-so)...