# error running sphinx due to dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python

Tags: python, path, python-sphinx, dyld

I'm trying to use sphinx to build documentation of a package I'm developing.  The commands I use used to work.  It looks like a link to a library has disappeared on my machine.  I'm using a Mac.

```
> sphinx-autobuild . _build/html
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
Reason: image not found
```

where XXX is my user name

Most similar question I can find is [pyside-rcc "dyld: Library not loaded:..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480902/pyside-rcc-dyld-library-not-loaded)
but the answer provided seems to be to copy over a bunch of files from one directory to another, which seems to risk causing other configuration problems.

Other answers relate to issues with

- virtualenv (which I am not using) [`dyld: Library not loaded` error preventing virtualenv from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading)
- brew + awscli (again, not being used by me) [How to resolve "dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path.." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629570/how-to-resolve-dyld-library-not-loaded-executable-path-error)

Based on the questions I've seen, it looks like I should fix this by changing the path.  Currently

```
>echo $PATH
```

`Applications/anaconda/bin:/Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`

My .bash_profile is

```
# added by Anaconda 2.1.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin:$PATH"


# Added by Canopy installer on 2016-08-08
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make the bash prompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
alias activate_canopy="source '/Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'"
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/Applications/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

That activate command that canopy is doing looks to be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing

```
alias activate_canopy="source '/Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'"
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/XXX/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'
```

from my .bash_profile.  Still waiting to see if this breaks Canopy.